# How to get the First to End item from an associative PHP array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I had an array like:

```
$fuel[0]->fuel_qty = 1.00
$fuel[1]->fuel_qty = 2.00
```

The following function gets the first element (1.00) of the array.

```
public function printFuel($id) {
    $fuel = $this->Fuel_model->directFuelQtyById($id);      
    $this->amount_word = $this->convert_number_to_words($fuel[0]->fuel_qty) . '<br>'." Only";
}
```

And I wanted to get all the array elements (1.00, 2.00 etc..) by modifying this function. How can I get this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: loop thru this array and get each element using `foreach` or `for` loop.

Comment: @ Serghei Leonenco. Can you update with modified code ?

Comment: `foreach($fuel as $obj){ $this->amount_word = $this->convert_number_to_words($obj->fuel_qty) . '<br>'." Only"; }` something like this.

Comment: @ Serghei Leonenco. But that prints only the second element (2.00)

Comment: I told you something like that, but if you want to print each one: `foreach($fuel as $obj){ echo $this->convert_number_to_words($obj->fuel_qty) . '<br>'." Only"; }`

Comment: @Serghei Leonenco. I used <td><p style="position: absolute;top: 20cm;right: 8cm"><?=$this->amount_word?></p></td> to print this elements using my view. Therefore, your first suggestion is correct. But printed only the second element on the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201169/discussion-between-serghei-leonenco-and-mcode).

Answer (score 0):

To get the last element use array_pop: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

To get the first element use array_shift: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php